# URLFetchApp returning Turn on JavaScript

Tags: php, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a simple PHP application running on Google Cloud Platform (Not published, just under development).

```
<?php
  echo "Hello World";
?>
```

When I type the URL into a browser it shows "Hello World". Very simple.

I have Apps Script code attempting to use URLFetchApp on the URL:

```
  var URL = "https://8080-dot-XXXXXXXX-dot-devshell.appspot.com/?authuser=0&environment_id=default";
  var option = {
    "method": "get",
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, option);
```

The Response Code is 200 and the Response Text is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Please turn on JavaScript in your browser to continue</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"></head><body ><p>You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.</p><p>Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.</p></body></html>
```

I've tried every permutation of followRedirects and muteHttpExceptions.

What am I doing wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you directly access that URL in the browser. Can you check the response text.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my request. When pasting the URL into a browser, it shows "Hello World" as one would expect. I'm confused by the HTML response saying, "Please turn on JavaScript in your browser" since its not a "browser" making the request, its "UrlFetchApp" and I don't see any parameters to the function indicating anything about JavaScript. I do appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: If you can provide the actual URL, that would help debug the issue better.

Comment: I appreciate that request, and I wish I could provide the actual URL. I really appreciate your willingness to try and replicate and debug this issue. While in my google cloud account, I have to run: "php -S localhost 8080" to get this to work. Since the account is ephemeral, it resets 30 minutes after I log out. So, unless I happen to be in the account and running "php' at the exact moment you try to test, the "php" won't be running when you test. So, as much as I would like, I don't know know to accommodate your request.